# Hexadecimal Validation Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to validate a hexadecimal number and its not going too well. I'm trying the code below but my logic isn't exactly on the ball. Any help?

```
if (!array[i].equals("A") || !array[i].equals("B") || !array[i].equals("C") || !array[i].equals("D") || !array[i].equals("E") || !array[i].equals("F")) 
  {
  b[i] = false;
  }
  else
  {
  b[i] = true;
  }
```

The aim of the above code is to give me a true or false value. True being the value is between A to F false being the value isn't between A to F.

Comment: you should probably use `.equalsIgnoreCase()` instead as well

Comment: I'd use a regex for this and what about the digits?

Comment: wouldn't a hexadecimal number also allow `0-9` ?

Comment: @Peter The digits worked fine but I was having trouble with this part so I deleted the digits out and focused on the specific code I was having trouble with. 

And I've already set the array to all upper case before hand but thanks Jarrod!

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((array[i]-'A') > 5)
b[i]=false;
else 
b[i]=true;
```

Comment: I've decided to use your idea but everytime I enter anything above F it throws an exception?

Comment: @user1861156 Handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Change all `||` to `&&`.

Right now your `if` condition always evaluates to `true` (since *any* string is not equal to either `"A"` or `"B"`).

Alternatively, replace the whole construct with:

```
b[i] = array[i].equals("A") || array[i].equals("B") || array[i].equals("C") ||
       array[i].equals("D") || array[i].equals("E") || array[i].equals("F");
```

Comment: or take away all the `!` and reverse the `true` and `false` statements

Comment: Not enough sleep, my excuse. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (array[i].equals("A") || array[i].equals("B") || array[i].equals("C") || array[i].equals("D") || array[i].equals("E") || array[i].equals("F")) 
{ b[i] = true; }
else 
{ b[i] = false; }
```

alternatively you could use a `List` and use [`.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) as well.

```
List<String> hexchars = new ArrayList<String>();
hexchars.add("A");
hexchars.add("B");
hexchars.add("C");
hexchars.add("D");
hexchars.add("E");
hexchars.add("F");
return hexchars.contains("A");
```

But a regular expression would be the cleanest way to do this in the long run.